# list all the label and value from a group field type in ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, acfpro

I really need some help, My problem is that I cannot show the label from a group field using ACF

Script below is displaying the name and value, I need the "Label" to be displayed and its "value" and I can't find anything.

```
if( have_rows('product_specifications') ): 
    while( have_rows('product_specifications') ): the_row(); 
    $subfields = get_field('product_specifications'); 
    if( $subfields ) { ?>
    <ul> 
        <?php
        foreach ($subfields as $spec => $value) {
        if ( !empty($value) ) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $spec; ?> : <?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php }
        } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php }
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Here is my current output:

```
lamp_type : E27
wattage : 1x 60W Max
globe_included : 1
colour_cord : Clear
```

when It should be:

```
Lamp Type : E27
Wattage : 1x 60W Max
Globe : 1
Colour Cord : Clear
```

Please anyone help me...

Comment: Need help please :-(

Comment: if I use get_field_object I get the labels but values are NULL but when I use get_field values are there but labels are gone, how can I combine these two functions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`get_row()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_row) to get the sub fields:

```
$subfields = get_row();
```

And use [`get_sub_field_object()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field_object) to get the sub field *object*:

```
$field = get_sub_field_object( $key );
```

So, try this: *(no re-indentation so that you can easily compare with your code)*

```
if( have_rows('product_specifications') ):
    while( have_rows('product_specifications') ): the_row();
    if( $subfields = get_row() ) { ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ($subfields as $key => $value) {
        if ( !empty($value) ) { $field = get_sub_field_object( $key ); ?>
        <li><?php echo $field['label']; ?> : <?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php }
        } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php }
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: this is the answer I have been looking for all these days, thank you so much @Sally CJ, will review first before I give the bounty, thanks again, you rock

Comment: Sure, take your time. =)

Comment: bounty award is set to 15hours from now so will do that tomorrow, thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking forward within the `foreach` loop is using the `get_field_object()` function.

Within here, you can get the label and value of any field.

For examples / uses of the `get_field_object()`, take a look at https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/.

So, for example, you'll have:

```
$field = get_field_object($spec);
echo $field['label'] . ': ' . $field['value'];
```

Hope this helps.